# Repeatable field using easy content manager

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress to create the cms . I am stuck on one point i have to ask from the user 2 fields

```
 1) Name
 2) Address
```

both fields are repeatable in the form of group . Is there any way that i define both in the form of group  using easy content manager plugin .

Comment: http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/

Comment: is it like i have to switch to this plugin and have to create all those pages again ? I am sorry i am new to wordpress .